# Illegal instruction in a shared library in Linux using an Intel Quark

Tags: c++, c, linux, assembly, intel

I've got a linux ".a" library which is compiled to work for x86. I don't have the source code of this library, and the programmer won't give me it. I got no problems running my programs in a PC with this architecture, however recently I bough an embedded system that has an Intel Quark processor. This processor has a reduced instruction set, so when I compile my program and try to run it I got a clear message: "Illegal instruction".

I know this isn't a memory violation problem, because when I debug it using GDB it exactly fails in an instruction with an opcode like CMOVE, which belongs to the CMOVxx instruction set introduced in Pentium Pro processors. In my embedded linux system (Ubuntu 14.04) /proc/cpuinfo "flags" field doesn't shows "cmov", so this is confirmed.

So, how can I override this problem?

Does it exist any kind of wrapper to translate this opcodes to another quark-friendly instructions? I know how to do it in Windows using OllyDbg (which allows ASM patching and saving executables) but there is no a similar solution like this in Linux that I'm aware of.

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: Have you looked around if http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ provides any useful q/a already? I personally would probably disassemble, change instructions and reassemble..

Comment: Can't you ask the supplier of the library to recompile the library for an older CPU ?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: this is a good approach, do you have any idea of a disassembler that produces compilable code aswell for Linux ELF? I mean in ASM, not C or so.

Comment: @PaulR: this is not possible, the supplier seems to have disappeared off the face of the earth.

Answer (score 5):

1. You can try [this uncommitted kernel patch](http://lwn.net/Articles/3874/) which emulates CMOV in the kernel.
2. You can install a `SIGILL` signal handler and [emulate the instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314755/in-a-sigill-handler-how-can-i-skip-the-offending-instruction) in your program only.

Comment: This is a great help, the second options seems to fit a good solution for me. Do you have any extra suggestion on managing this signal?

Comment: Basically you need to get EIP from the context, read the instruction, check that it's CMOV, and change the register values to simulate its effect. See the code marked `/* CMOV* */` in the kernel patch.